# Solr performance tweaking for faster query / indexing, rather than the storage requirements

Tags: solr, solrj, lucene, solr4j

We are looking for ways to improve query/index performance on solr. We are not concerned about the storage requirements. We have lot of storage space.

Essentially we want to speed up solr query/indexing by throwing more storage at the solr index.

I have already reviewed http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors. But it doesn't cover this particular scenario.

p.s. you can tell me that this is a stupid question, and i won't mind :)

Comment: you can have a lot of different machines also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing side:

You could potentially increase the speed of indexing by using very high mergeFactors. Thus there will be very many Lucene index segments that will merge at slow speed (basically, merging is what takes quite a lot of time). Then by the time you are done with indexing, set the mergeFactor back to something sensible, like 10. This will make sure you have only few segments to read through.

Also consider SSDs, some folks have reported better perf with these.

Querying side:
It is nearly impossible to recommend anything without knowing your particalur setup and use case. But monitor the cache usage. If you have high utilization rate of a particular cache, yet evictions, get rid of them by giving more RAM.